# activemq client not receiving the message from queue

Tags: activemq-classic

We are trying to run JMS application using ActiveMQ, we are facing a problem with the message receiver. Please find below process used by the application and test.

1. A scheduler based JMS application starts
2. A persistent activemq test message is placed into a queue
3. The scheduled event tries to receive the message from the queue(this is not a consumer but it is just a receiver jmsTemplate.receive(queue))

Even though the message is there in the queue which can be browsed using activemq console, the application doesn't see it and says no message received in the queue. This issue happening even for a single input message, I have tried all the config options suggested over the support sites but nothing works. This is how my activemq.xml broker tag is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" persistent="true" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000" deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true">
   <destinationPolicy>
      <policyMap>
         <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry queue="&gt;" maxPageSize="5000" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="300000">
               <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                  <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000" />
               </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
         </policyEntries>
      </policyMap>
   </destinationPolicy>
   <managementContext>
      <managementContext createConnector="false" />
   </managementContext>
   <persistenceAdapter>
      <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb" />
   </persistenceAdapter>
</broker>
```

Can someone please suggest anything that I am missing?

Edit:

Here is the receiver code

```
private javax.jms.Message getMessageFromQueue(String jmsCorrelationID, String queueName)
            throws JMSException, EdiRoutingException, DcQueueNameMapperException {
        String messageSelector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + jmsCorrelationID + "'";
        javax.jms.Message message = jmsTemplate.receiveSelected(queueName, messageSelector);
        if(null != message) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            auditMessage("DATA", textMessage.getText());
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Here is the producer code:

```
 public void sendMessage(String queueName, final String jmsCorrelationId, final String message) {
        jmsTemplate.send(queueName, session -> {
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jmsCorrelationId)) {
                textMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(jmsCorrelationId);
            }
            return textMessage;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please post your application code which receives the message

Comment: @tomredfern, I have included the message producer and receiver code in the question. Thanks